# UML dependency relationship - should I use it here?

Tags: dependencies, uml, delegation

If I have a class "Foo" that contains an instance of "Delegate". Foo delegates method calls to class "Delegate" like so:

```
public class Foo {
   private Delegate delegate = new Delegate();

   public void bar() {
      delegate.bar();
   }
}
```

When I draw the Foo class in UML, would it have a dependency relationship (dashed line with an arrowhead) between it and the Delegate class, or would it have a line representing a Composition relationship instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about UML is that you have some leeway, but in your case, IMHO, dependency is better.

You don't have a `delegate` as a property of a `Foo` (there is no `getDelegate`) so no one looking at your system would really care that a `Foo` was composed of a delegate (among other things).

Then again, if your UML diagram was given to a tool that would generate code from a diagram, it might. :)

Do what feels right to the people (or agents) to whom you are giving the diagram.

Comment: I wouldn't use absence of the getter as a strong indicator. I never liked dependencies in UML myself that much. Basic things from OO are adequately covered, so I mostly use them when I do non-OO modelling. But if no-one needs to know what Foo does internally, then I won't argue ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the composition relationship in that case. If you haven't decided yet whether Foo will contain an instance of Delegate, then a dependency relationship is fine. But if you've made that decision already, then there is no advantage to hiding the additional information, in fact it could be misleading (a reader may think that it is NOT a containment cos if it was, it would be shown as such).

Comment: Hi. I have decided that Foo *will* contain an instance of Delegate. So, should it stay as a dependency? Thanks

Comment: In that case I would use a Composition relationship.